# How to locate an element with tag <a classname="xxx" href="xxx"> in ScalaTest +Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scalatest

I have an element which needs to be clicked for Date layout. The locator corresponding to the element I found is classname="xxx" and below gives my scalatest code to click on the particular element.
when I run the script, it gives "web element not found" exception. Can you please guide on this

```
Code:
        click on className("selectedBtnDate")

element Inspector:
        <li class="datepickertooltip">
        <span class="tooltiptext">Date</span>
        <a class="selectedBtnDate" href="#"></a>
        </li>
```

Comment: It depends how you set Selenium and ScalaTest to work together. I have a ScalaTest set up with Selenium and I can use the 'driver' with no restrictions to select any element. I would simply call `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.selectedBtnDate[href='#']"))` to do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tom. I tried with the above code and now what happens is the element in webpage only gets highlighted. It should popup a frame which is not happening. Maybe the problem is with the browser controlled by the driver (chrome). It doesn't show any popup while clicking manually

Comment: It's strange that it doesn't pop up anything when the browser is opened by the driver. Can you check the js console in the browser, to see if there's any error? You can still try to click on the element using js, with [Javascript Executor]( https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). Maybe it's worth it to give it a try.